# Puppeteer: Toggle on/off switch

Tags: switch-statement, toggle, puppeteer

Is there any capability/long press in puppeteer to toggle on/off switch? I tried to focus and click but did not work. It is of type checkbox and is a slider.

input type="checkbox" id="status" name="status" role="switch" aria-checked="true"

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show your markup and current Puppeteer code as a [mcve].

Comment: Thank You, added. It is confidential and cannot share more.